# In Rails, allow will_paginate to be unlimited for a search on a separate page OR set a global will_paginate with override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

So in my dashboard I want for separate modules to have the normal will_paginate settings. However I have a module that pulls in data from all other models for search/filter. The problem at the moment is that the normal will_paginate settings is also affecting the search/filter. So for example Books currently has 300 items. When I use the search/filter in my Search Index it limits to only 30 based on will_paginate. Without hitting the models how do I increase the will_paginate on the Search Index alone?

Search Controller looks like:

```
class Admin::SearchesController < Admin::ApplicationController
  belongs_to_app :search
  add_breadcrumb 'Search', :admin_searches_path
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
  end

  def all_users
    @users = User.includes(
      :user_books, :books
    ).all

    render 'all_users'
  end

  def all_books
    respond_with UserBook.ordered
  end

end
```

Books Controller

```
class Admin::BooksController < Admin::ApplicationController
    belongs_to_app :books
    add_breadcrumb 'Books', :admin_books_path
    before_action :load_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    respond_to :html, :json

    def index
     @books = Book.paginate(page: params[:page])
     @books = @books.search(params[:search]) if params[:search]
     respond_with(@books)
    end
end
```

Then I'm using a jbuilder file

```
json.call(@users) do |user|
 json.name user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name
 json.email user.email

json.books(user.user_books) do |user_book|
 json.id user_book.book.id
 json.name user_book.book.name
end
end
```

Then pulling on the index with the following:

```
mounted: function() {
 var self = this;
 $.getJSON('/admin/all_users/').then(function(json) {
  self.allUsers = json;
 });
 $.getJSON('/admin/books/').then(function(json) {
  self.allBooks = json;
 });
```

I've tried playing around with the controller for Book to limit the page but that really didn't work and it was affecting the Books page which I definitely don't want. Just the results.

Edit:
Another option I'm trying to play around is putting in application_record.rb is WillPaginate.per_page = 999999.

This resolves the issue on the Search Index page on pulling in all Books. However the Books page is stripped of it's pagination. So then I add in on the controller:

```
@books = Book.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

This then limits the Search Index on pulling in all books and it's now limited to 10.

Is there a way for the ajax request to change that number based on the page?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for,  but have you taken a look at the docs ?. https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#user-content-basic-will_paginate-use there you'll find that you can pass a `per_page:` key to the `paginate` function, that way you can change how many results you want in that call.

Comment: Not exactly. So I don't really want to affect the models as that would affect the other views, per_page change on each controller would affect their views and that's something I don't want to do. Really I want to have the will_paginate either not affect the Searches Controller OR be unlimited.